How do I restore Azure bacpac to AWS RDS Instance
I have created a bacpac backup from Azure SQL database and I want to restore it to AWS RDS SQL server. But when I try to import the .bacpac file to RDS, I get the following error.

Error SQL72014: Core Microsoft SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 50000, Level 20, State 1, Procedure rds_deny_backups_trigger, Line 34 You cannot GRANT/REVOKE 'BACKUP DATABASE' or 'BACKUP LOG' permission for a user.
Error SQL72045: Script execution error.  The executed script:
REVOKE BACKUP DATABASE TO [xxxx] CASCADE;

I am using RDS master user to import the backup file but still getting the same error.  So may I know does anyone knows why we are getting this error?

Like it states in the error message: "You cannot GRANT/REVOKE 'BACKUP DATABASE' or 'BACKUP LOG' permission for a user". This may be due to AWS RDS’s restrictions on certain SQL Server permissions.
Please see this extensive article on how to Migrate SQL Server databases from an Azure SQL database to Amazon RDS for SQL Server using bacpac method.

I am using RDS master user to import the backup file but still getting the same error.

This is the same document that I followed. I am trying to restore the backup using sqlpackage to avoid permission issues but cannot identify why I am getting the mentioned error.

First of all I think you should contact the AWS support and ask them how to move.
Then, in my opinion, Azure SQL Database is not RDS and is not SQL Server.
So you should:

Take that bacpac backup and install it on a SQL Server 2019 or 2022
Now that the database has been imported successfully into SQL  Server take a backup of it
Import that backup to RDS

This way you are not migrating Azure SQL Database to RDS but SQL Server to RDS.
